# JAXB default values from xsd when generating beans with xjc

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, jaxb2, xjc

When generating java beans from xsd files I would like to have the default values defined in the xsd file pre-set in the java beans as well. The unmarshalling process does not care about xsd defaults, therefore I need them set at source generation time.

Can this be done? I'm using Maven with the xjcplugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [CXF XJC default plugin](https://cxf.apache.org/cxf-xjc-dv.html) or the [JAXB2 commons Default Value plugin](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb2-commons/tree/master/default-value-plugin).